# How can I keep files from being opened in System?

Tags: windows-8.1, file-management

I have a program (an old version of Delphi) that needs to create a temporary file whenever it is opened. Problem is, it can create that file, but it cannot overwrite it, so whenever I try to open it I have to move the file somewhere else first.

The file is created in the temp folder (userfolder\AppData\Local\Temp). I can move it anywhere, I can rename it, but I can't delete it.

So I have created a separate folder where I can move the temp file. I get one copy everytime I want to open the program, so I have been renaming these copies. But there are just too many of them now and I'd like to get rid of them.

When I try to delete one, I get a message that goes:

> The action can’t be completed because the file is open in System

The funny thing is that even if I reboot the system, when I go to the separate folder I've created to contain those files and try to delete one, I still get that message.

I have tried:

- Assigning myself ownership of the files (they originally belong to System);
- Assigning permissions to other user accounts, including "Everyone", and making sure that all of them have permission to delete the files;
- Removing all file attributes;
- Rebooting, as mentioned above. I even did it multiple times;
- Changing not only file names but also extensions;
- Unlocker (a program that promises to solve this kind of problem, but it didn't work for me);
- Going through the command prompt. It just says `access denied`.

What else can I try? How can I keep the System process from opening these files so that I can get rid of them?

Comment: Have you tried closing the temporary file first and then delete?

Comment: @suspectus I reboot the machine and immediatelly try to delete them, and I still get the error. I wish I knew how to keep them from being opened in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Good list of ideas. 
Other more extreme things to try:

- Boot into safe mode
- Mount disk in another machine

You can use [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what (if any) process has a handle on the file:

- Ctrl+L (show lower pane)
- In the lower pane, Ctrl+F for the filename